# AlertDialog texto de Botón en minúsculas

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente botón "Aceptar" en un `AlertDialog`:

```
  final AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this,android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
    }
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle("Informacion");
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialogoPasswordLogin));

    builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    final Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams positiveButtonLL = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
    positiveButtonLL.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    positiveButton.setLayoutParams(positiveButtonLL);
```

Pero el Aceptar por mas que le puse "Aceptar" aparece ACEPTAR

como podria lograr que no me deje todo en Mayúscula

desde ya gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto puedes cambiarlo sobre escribiendo el estilo del botón, deshabilitando la conversión a Mayúsculas.

En el tema principal que usa tu aplicación agrega el `item`:

```
 <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
```

y agregas el estilo

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Este sería un ejemplo completo:

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" ...
     ...
     ...
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

De esta forma el texto definido en los botones se mostraría sin ser convertido a mayúsculas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Exelente Jorge muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

Para agregar botones de acción llama a los métodos setPositiveButton() y setNegativeButton():

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
// Add the buttons
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User clicked OK button
           }
       });
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User cancelled the dialog
           }
       });
// Set other dialog properties
...

// Create the AlertDialog
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Los métodos set...Button() requieren un título para el botón (proporcionado por un recurso de string) y un DialogInterface.OnClickListener que defina la acción que se realizará cuando el usuario presione el botón.
solo cambia donde dice:

```
R.string.ok
```

en vez de ok pon lo que deseas
al igual con el de cancel..espero te sirva
suerte !!

Comment: Aunque se "defina" un texto en  R.string.ok este se continuaría mostrando en mayúsculas en el caso de los botones.esto en el AlertDialog ya que por default se convierten de minúsculas a mayúsculas.